# Groupping a list of tuples into sets with coordinate wise matching

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tuples

Suppose that there is a list of n l-tuples. One is interested in grouping this list into sets where each set containing m tuples such that there is a maximal match coordinate wise. For example:

input: {(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (2,3,1), (2,3,1), (4,3,1), (2,1,4)}, m = 3

output: {(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (2,1,4)}, {(2,3,1), (2,3,1), (4,3,1)}

It is important to note the possibility of those cases(with certain values for n and m) that result in having a set with fewer elements than others or a set with more elements than m elements(tuples).

Questions: What is the name of this problem in the literature? Is there exists an algorithm that performing this task? What about leaving the number of tuples in each partition, m not fixed, and determining the optimal such m with the given restriction, if it makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. If that is a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), could you elaborate on what exactly have you tried so far to find an answer, and where you stumbled?. Also, you are posting multiple questions.

Comment: Hello and thank you, @MichaelSchönbauer. This is not a homework question, it is just a question that I have been formulated yesterday evening after a discussion with a friend. I am still trying to solve it, taking into consideration small cases. Nevertheless, didn't come up with something worth sharing, except the problem itself, which I find interesting(if it formulated properly though). In such questions, if I am not mistaken, there is already a theory developed, hence I am asking for the name of the problem if such exists. The second and third questions could be separated.

Comment: You need to define what _maximal match_ is.